# how to prevent this infinite loop in powershell?

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, cat

While referring to [this](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex15.html) tutorial on command line after executing the following commands in the PowerShell, it goes in a infinite loop.

```
echo "I am a new file." > ex15.txt
cat ex15.txt > another.txt
cat *.txt > bigfile.txt
```

After firing the last command the execution never ends.It goes in an infinite loop. But this works fine in command prompt using the type command.

```
type *.txt > bigfile.txt
```

This command doesn't go into an infinite loop. This works perfectly. Why this isn't working in the PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mjolinor explained, `Get-Content` is reading the data you're adding to bigfile.txt just as fast as writing it, resulting in a command that will never end.

The easiest solution to this is to put bigfile.txt into a different directory, so it isn't one of the files that you are reading.  Eg: The parent directory.

```
cat *.txt > ..\bigfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

`Cat (Get-Content)` in Powershell works differently than the `type` command in cmd.

`Type` will not see the bigfile.txt being written, but `Get-Content` will and you end up reading bigfile.txt and writing out to the same file so it's stuck in a loop.

To prevent the loop, you can force cat to finish reading all the files before it writes by wrapping the cat expression in parens:

```
(cat *.txt) > bigfile.txt
```

Comment: Or put bigfile.txt into a different directory.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Even after wrapping the expression in parenthesis I get the same infinite loop.

Comment: @RyanBemrose Yes, putting the fie in another directory works.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant would be to exclude 'bigfile.txt' from the files in the current path that you want to read:

```
cat (ls *.txt -Exclude bigfile.txt) > bigfile.txt
```